# Why is the AWS SSM SDK caching results of DescribeParametersCommand and how to avoid this

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-ssm

I am currently having some strange behaviour with the `@aws-sdk/client-ssm` AWS Node.JS SDK.  The following code is incorrectly printing `length:0`

```
import {SSMClient, PutParameterCommand, ParameterType, DescribeParametersCommand, DeleteParametersCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ssm";

const client = new SSMClient({});
const name = 'param-name';

// clean up to allow multiple runs
await client.send(new DeleteParametersCommand({ Names: [name] }));

// make first 'list' call
const res1 = await client.send(new DescribeParametersCommand({}));
const list1 = (res1.Parameters || []).filter(p => p.Name === name);

// add parameter
(await client.send(new PutParameterCommand({ Name: name, Value: 'value', Type: ParameterType.STRING })))

// expect second 'list' to show this newly added parameter
const res2 = await client.send(new DescribeParametersCommand({}));
const list2 = (res2.Parameters || []).filter(p => p.Name === name);

// length=0.  However, if we comment out first `client.send(new DescribeParametersCommand({}))` above then length=1
console.log('length:', list2.length);
```

However, if I comment out the first call to `client.send(new DescribeParametersCommand({}))` then the correct value is logged: `length: 1`:

```
...
// make first 'list' call
// const res1 = await client.send(new DescribeParametersCommand({}));
// const list1 = (res1.Parameters || []).filter(p => p.Name === name);
...
const res2 = await client.send(new DescribeParametersCommand({}));
const list2 = (res2.Parameters || []).filter(p => p.Name === name);

// length=0.  However, if we comment out first `client.send(new DescribeParametersCommand({}))` above then length=1
console.log('length:', list2.length);
```

It appears that the result to `DescribeParametersCommand` is being cached?  However, there is nothing about caching in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-ssm/classes/describeparameterscommand.html) or anything about invalidating the cache.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I'm stuck on the same thin (using @aws-sdk/client-device-farm).

Answer (score 0):

Raised a [ticket for this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/4349) the answer ended up being that the SSM client is not atomic (eventually consistent?).  Even though this is not mentioned in the docs (at least at the time I raised the ticket).

The actual response from was tech was:

> It has been executed, but even if the server gives you a 200, it takes the record time to be created and propagated throughout AWS. So you have written to it, but reading from it might take an extra second that your next await calls already fired and returned.

See the [ticket link](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/4349) for full discussion